# Want to stop system service when "Force Stop" on my app is called

Tags: android

I am working on an app that starts a service AND a system service. If "Force Close" is clicked on my app from settings, my app and service are stopped, but I'd also like for the system service to be stopped as well. I understand that I won't receive an onDestroy callback.

It's complicated and I can't really get into the business reasons why this is a problem. I'm just wondering if it's possible to do.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of system service? are you working on a rooted device?

Comment: It's not rooted. The service is a non-essential 3rd party service that my app starts and stops under normal use. I suppose that's a good way to abstract it: Can you start an external service (i.e. not my app) in such a way that if the app that started the service is forced closed, the service is also stopped.

Comment: No, this is impossible on an unrooted device. The service you started from your app may run in a totally different process.